# angular resource return list for query error translation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to use Angular resource to pull down a list of projects from a API. The api works if I hit from browser and using swagger, I get a json list of projects.

But not been able to get past errors in angular to output the resulting list on a page.

```
.factory('ProjectsDS', ['$resource','$timeout',
                        function($resource, $timeout){console.log(0);

                        var proj = $resource('/projects');
                            $timeout(2000);
                        console.log( 0 + ' ' + proj.query().length);


                          return $resource('/projects')}])
```

Error in browser console:

```
"Error: [$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$resource/badcfg?p0=Error%20in%20resource%20configuration%20for%20action%20%60%7B0%7D%60.%20Expected%20response%20to%20contain%20an%20%7B1%7D%20but%20got%20an%20%7B2%7D%20(Request%3A%20%7B3%7D%20%7B4%7D)&p1=query&p2=array&p3=object&p4=GET&p5=%2Fprojects
O/<@http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:6:412
resourceFactory/</Resource[name]/promise<@http://localhost:8000/js/angular-resource.js:682:25
e/<@http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:130:226
tf/this.$get</n.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:144:463
tf/this.$get</n.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:142:39
tf/this.$get</n.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:145:247
l@http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:97:53
H@http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:101:190
dg/</u.onload@http://localhost:8000/js/angular.min.js:102:229
"
```

Using the timeout to handle, I think, the initial empty return object. Length does output 0.

API returns if browsed to:

```
{"_links":{"self":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/projects?page=1"},"first":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/projects"},"last":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/projects?page=1"}},"_embedded":{"projects":[{"id":"1","message":null,"timestamp":null,"user":null,"name":"First 1","site":"https:\/\/www.nathanhaley.com","description":"This is one description.","_links":{"self":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/projects\/1"}}},{"id":"2","message":null,"timestamp":null,"user":null,"name":"First 1","site":"https:\/\/www.nathanhaley.com","description":"This is one description.","_links":{"self":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/projects\/2"}}},{"id":"3","message":null,"timestamp":null,"user":null,"name":"First 2","site":"https:\/\/www.nathanhaley.com","description":"This is one description.","_links":{"self":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/projects\/3"}}},{"id":"4","message":null,"timestamp":null,"user":null,"name":"First 12","site":"https:\/\/www.nathanhaley.com","description":"This is one description.","_links":{"self":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/projects\/4"}}}]},"page_count":1,"page_size":25,"total_items":4,"page":1}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [error that is logged:](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=Error%20in%20resource%20configuration%20for%20action%20%60%7B0%7D%60.%20Expected%20response%20to%20contain%20an%20%7B1%7D%20but%20got%20an%20%7B2%7D%20(Request:%20%7B3%7D%20%7B4%7D)&p1=query&p2=array&p3=object&p4=GET&p5=%2Fprojects)

> This error occurs when the $resource service expects a response that
>   can be deserialized as an array but receives an object, or vice versa.

On this line: `console.log( 0 + ' ' + proj.query().length);` try using `.get()` instead of `.query()`

Comment: thanks but while console shows [object Object] , if I take the length off as that yields undefined, as does proj.get()[0]. So it seems like an empty object to me or how do I check. If I just run proj.query() I get an empty array to the console like Array{ }.

Comment: I forgot -- $resource returns a promise. To access the data returned from the api, the promise needs to be resolved. Try `proj.get().$promise.then(function (result) { console.log(result) })`. As an aside, are you generally familiar with promises/async functions? I'm relatively new to promises myself. I implemented $resource when I first started working with promises, but it was then recommended that I learn $http first. Now I'm using $http on my current project and it's much simpler and fits my needs just fine. Definitely learn $resource if you can, but $http is easier to start with

Comment: Also, the $timeout should not be necessary as the promise will resolve when data is returned

Comment: Thank you, looking at the data in context of an object as you recommended I was able to reference the collection/list as basically data._embedded.projects.